# Different serial keys with different options in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

How to provide multiple serial number with multiple options in Inno Setup?

I want to write different values in Registry, based on different serial keys I provide to customers.

Ex different serial keys like:

```
sKey1 = "A1AA-B2ACF-HEJUI-UYTER"
sKey2 = "A1BB-B2ACF-HEJUI-UYTER"
sKey3 = "A1CC-B2ACF-HEJUI-UYTER"
```

First 4 characters or different for different keys want to create in Registry

```
if (custInput.startwith ("A1AA") then
    Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Version\"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"Name";ValueData: "{"Lite"}"; 
elseif  (custInput.startwith ("A1BB") then
    Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Version\"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"Name";ValueData: "{"Pro"}"; 
elseif  (custInput.startwith ("A1CC") then
    Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Version\"; ValueType:string; ValueName:"Name";ValueData: "{"Online"}"; 
endif
```

How to achieve this in Inno Setup? I used `CheckSerial` function below:

```pascal
function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := Serial = '{#SerialNumber}';
  end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to programatically decide about the value to store to the registry:

```
[Setup]
UserInfoPage=yes

[Registry]
Root: "HKLM"; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Version"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "Name"; \
    ValueData: "{code:GetEdition}";
```

```pascal
[Code]

var
  Serials: TStrings;
  Editions: TStrings;

function CheckSerial(Serial: String): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Serials.IndexOf(Serial) >= 0);
end;

procedure RegisterEdition(Serial: string; Edition: string);
begin
  Serials.Add(Serial);
  Editions.Add(Edition);
end;

function GetEdition(Param: string): string;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := Serials.IndexOf(WizardForm.UserInfoSerialEdit.Text);
  if Index >= 0 then Result := Editions[Index];
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Serials := TStringList.Create;
  Editions := TStringList.Create;

  RegisterEdition('A1AA-B2ACF-HEJUI-UYTER', 'Lite');
  RegisterEdition('A1BB-B2ACF-HEJUI-UYTER', 'Pro');
  RegisterEdition('A1CC-B2ACF-HEJUI-UYTER', 'Online');

  Result := True;
end;
```