# Inno Setup compiler throws error "is ('=') expected" on constant array declaration

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am experiencing a compiler error saying:

> Line 70:
> Column: 19
> is ('=') expected

What did I do wrong?

```pascal
[Code]
// Define the allowed passwords
const
  allowedPasswords: array[0..1] of string = ('Passwort1', 'Passwort2');

function IsPasswordValid(password: string): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  // Check if the entered password is in the list of allowed passwords
  for i := Low(allowedPasswords) to High(allowedPasswords) do
  begin
    if password = allowedPasswords[i] then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;

  // If the password is not in the list of allowed passwords, return false
  Result := False;
end;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because Inno Setup Pascal Script does not support explicitly typed constants. So  after the constant name (`allowedPasswords`), the only acceptable symbol is the equal sign (`=`) followed by a constant value.

Moreover the Pascal Script does not support array constants.

For alternative code to create array of acceptable values, see:

- [How to do a dynamic password in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34626502/850848)

Though in many cases, using [`TStringList`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TStringList) is more convenient:

- [Evaluate a collection of data from preprocessor on run time in Inno Setup Pascal Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60971940/850848)
- [Inno Setup: Different Serial keys with different options?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62167500/850848)
- [Inno Setup - Check if multiple folders exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44274005/850848)

Answer (score 0):

As Martin said: PascalScript in Inno Setup does not support typed constants.

As a quick substitute, you can use `TArrayOfString`, `SetArrayLength`, and assign values to the individual array elements; e.g.:

```
var
  AllowedPasswords: TArrayOfString;
```

and

```
SetArrayLength(AllowedPasswords, 2);
AllowedPasswords[0] := 'password1';
AllowedPasswords[1] := 'password2';
```